# How to customize the html of the course box in Moodle?

Tags: render, moodle

I need to customize the html structure of the course box in the Moodle.
I'm new to moodle so please help me!

/course/renderer.php

Inside that file I found several functions that generate coursebox html.
But I'm wondering it is no problem to update that functions or not.

Is there anyway to override course renderer in moodle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do just that if you create your own theme. The moodlewiki has a page on that:
[Overriding a renderer](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer)